# Cómo lograr el control de clientes en WooCommerce

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-plugin

tengo una tienda con WordPress, Woocommerce y necesito tener usuarios encargados de tienda (gestor de la tienda) los cuales deben controlar a los usuarios de tipo cliente, cada gestor de la tienda debe tener asignado un cierto grupo de clientes y en el administrador debe ver solamente la información de los mismos asignados. He buscado, investigado y probado diversas herramientas en busca de la funcionalidad que necesito sin llegar al resultado esperado, si alguien conoce algún plugin o similar para trabajar el requerimiento agradecería su recomendación y/o ayuda o definitivamente debería desarrollar un complemento específico.

Comment: cómo definis "un cierto grupo de clientes"?  que los diferencia? cómo se agrupan? por tienda? por producto? por codigo onda referal? que tipo de estructura comercial estan intentando plasmar? franquicias? revendedores? una vez que tengas esas respuestas las buscas en inglés y seguro salta algo. sino es filtrar por roles y capabilities via código o usando plugins onda [ACP](https://www.admincolumns.com/woocommerce-columns/) + [AAM](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-access-manager/) + [AME](https://wordpress.org/plugins/admin-menu-editor/)

Comment: Hola, por ejemplo tengo 3 gestores de tiendas, cada uno debe estar a cargo de cierto grupo de clientes (desde el administrador de wp, wooc.), ejemplo: gestor 1 esta a cargo de "cliente 1,2,3...", gestor 2 a cargo de "cliente 4,5,6.." y así sucesivamente, no he logrado realizar la agrupación y luego asignar. gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: Dudo que encuentres un plugin para eso, necesitarás revisar la documentación para lograrlo, la forma mas facil seria agregar el rol de gestor de la tienda y asignarlo un metadato, tipo "user_asigned " con los ids de los usuarios, luego puedes crear un custom admin page y mostrar ahí el loop con esos id's de usuario y mostrarles a los gestores esa pagina, asi cada quien vería sus datos, pero necesitaras tener conocimiento relativamente avanzado para lograrlo.

Comment: Por favor evita duplicar preguntas, sobre todo si en esta nueva publicación aún no has corregido los aspectos que llevaron al cierre de la anterior, por favor lee [ask]

Comment: me encuentro trabajando en ello, pero no soy un gran experto con WordPress y WooCommerce, continuaré con mi búsqueda y pruebas.